# GMSAutocompleteFilter type deprecated

Tags: swift

I'm getting this warning:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .address -> **'type' is deprecated: type property is deprecated in favor of types**
```

Ok... so I look at the official documentation and they tell me I should use this instead:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.types = [.address]
```

...I do that and get this error:

**Type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String') has no member 'address'**

[image: tyes error]

I don't understand what's worng. The library is up to date.

Comment: I am in this same position. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @KinneyKare - nope. Just left ".type" and waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected type for the property `types` is array of strings. If you look at the definition of `GMSAutocompleteFilter`, the link regarding filter types is mentioned.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/supported_types#table1

If you don't specify any type, it returns the list of addresses.

Try this code (Swift 5.7 and above) -

```
func fetch() {
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.countries = ["AU"]
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: searchText, filter: filter, sessionToken: nil) { predictions, error in
        if let error {
            return print("error \(error)")
        }
        if let results = predictions {
            if results.isEmpty { return print("No result found") }

            _ = results.map {
                print("Primary - \($0.attributedPrimaryText)")
                print("Secondary - \(String(describing: $0.attributedSecondaryText))")
                print("Full - \($0.attributedFullText)")
                print("Types - \($0.types)")
                return $0.attributedFullText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I print the filter types as well that I think are used internally by API to search the place.

Most of the types that I received are `"route"` and `"geocode"`.

What I deduced from the documentation link, that table 3 has broader filters while table 1 has very specific filters.

So, if you pass filter types "address", it will try to provide possible accurate address.

```
filter.types = ["address"]
```

Answer (score -1):

types is a String array so just keep the first one

```
place.addressComponents?.first(where: { $0.types.first == "postal_code" })?.name
```

Comment: Your solution is a workaround but it's not really what I was looking for. If you look here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete
you'll see that the recommended method is:
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.types = [.address]
The problem is that it gives an error in xCode and I don't know why.